# How can I use Transactional scope in SSIS using MS Access databases?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ssis

Using MS Access DB is nearly always a pain. What really hurts is that you can't even use a distributed transaction in SSIS when utilizing an OLE-DB Connection accessing an MS Access file. EVEN IF YOU ONLY INTEND TO READ IT! WTF? What kind of transaction support is that? So can anybody tell me how to make a SSIS package transactional in this case? Using the normal Transaction mode results in a `The Acquire Connection manager failed with error code 0xC0202009`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into scenarios like this (ancient MySQL instance and a DB2 where they denied us create transaction rights) and what I found to be an effective solution is to cache the source that doesn't support transactions in a [raw file](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/12/12/SSIS_3A00_-Dropping-data-into-a-raw-file.aspx), cache connection manager, or a recordset destination. Raw file would be my "go to" for sheer simplicity sake but the others may be needed based on component requirements.

General appearance of a package would look like: Package (or enclosing container) with transaction set to Required. This will create a transaction that contained tasks can enlist in. I then create a "starter" container that explicitly opts out of a transaction (transaction option: notsupported). That's where we will want to access the resource that doesn't support transactions. The default transaction option, Supported, means it will enlist in an open transaction if one is available. I put all the tasks that need the transaction in the supported container.

[image: Package non-transactional layout]

In the dataflow that is outside the transaction, I dump to a RAW file. I use the same query that I'd use in a "normal" transaction supported source.

[image: local cache]

In the data flow that consumes the cache output, I use the file generated in the first step and voila, transactions working as intended for the destination and no transaction attempted on the source that didn't support it.

[image: cache source]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `RetainSameConnection` property on the OLE DB Connection Manager to `True`, e.g. when writing to a SQL Server as seen [here](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/08/20/SSIS-Nugget_3A00_-RetainSameConnection-property-of-the-OLE-DB-Connection-Manager.aspx). This in return enables you to write a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` in one **Execute SQL Task** and then choose to `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` in another one.

But Beware: Avoid loose ends as this will create multiple connections when running tasks parallel. You have to create a chain from BEGIN TRAN to COMMIT, otherwise it will fail.

See http://www.morrenth.com/transaction-and-retainsameconnection-in-ssis-ole-db-connection-manager.aspx